# How can I implement RefreshIndicator in Listview.Builder using Getx?

Tags: android, flutter, api, flutter-getx, flutter-listview

I want to implement `RefreshIndicator` in my `Listview.builder` but the problem is that when I place `RefreshIndicator` it's not working. And I search in Google the answer that I find is that place physic:

`AlwaysScrollableScroll()` in `Listview.Builder` and when I try it `RefreshIndicator` worked but `Listview.Builder` not working and I search in Google the answer that I find is that place physic:

`NeverScrollableScroll()` in `Listview.Builder` then My `Listview.Builder` is working OK but Refresh Indicator not working. What can I do?

I am little bit confused, what I can do: either I place `AlwaysScrollableScroll()` or `NeverScrollable()`.

Here is my code:

```
  return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        FirstRow(
          headingText: 'My Appointments',
          context: context,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Obx(() {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              AppButtonLarge(
                  selected: appointmentController.appointmentT ==
                          'upcomingAppointments' ??
                      false,
                  text: 'Upcoming',
                  onTap: onAppointmentChange),
              AppButtonLarge(
                  selected: appointmentController.appointmentT ==
                          'pastAppointments' ??
                      false,
                  text: 'Past',
                  onTap: onAppointmentChange),
            ],
          );
        }),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  GetX<DoctorAppointmentController>(
                    builder: (controller) {
                      // List<Appointment> controller.appointmentList=[];
                      // allAppointment.forEach((element) {
                      // if(element!=null){
                      //   controller.appointmentList=controller.appointmentList+element;
                      // }
                      // });
                      // List<Appointment> controller.appointmentList=snapshot.data;
                      print(controller.appointmentList.length);
                      return controller.isLoading.value
                          ? AppWidgetsCard.getProgressIndicator()
                          : controller.appointmentList.length > 0
                              ? RefreshIndicator(
                            key: refreshKey,
                        onRefresh: () async{
                          await Navigator.pushReplacement(context, PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (a,b,c)=>GetAllDrAppointments(),
                              transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 3)));
                        },
                                child: Obx(()=>ListView.builder(

                                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                    // reverse: true,

                                    itemCount: controller.appointmentList.length,
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        void goToNext() {
                                          Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    MyAppointments(
                                                        appointment: controller
                                                                .appointmentList[
                                                            index], isDoctor: true),
                                              ));
                                        }

                                        if (index ==
                                            controller.appointmentList.length -
                                                1) {
                                          id = controller
                                              .appointmentList[index].id;

                                          return Column(
                                            children: [
                                              TextButton(
                                                  onPressed: goToNext,
                                                  child: AppWidgetsCard
                                                      .getAppointmentCard(
                                                          controller.appointmentList[index],
                                                          goToNext, isDoctor:  true), ),
                                              Obx(
                                                () {
                                                  return controller.loadMore.value
                                                      ? AppWidgetsCard
                                                          .getProgressIndicator()
                                                      : Container(
                                                          height: 40,
                                                          width: 200,
                                                          child: AppMethodButton(
                                                              selected: true,
                                                              text: 'Load More',
                                                              onTapMethod: () {
                                                                print('data');
                                                                controller
                                                                    .fetchMoreAppointments(
                                                                        id);
                                                              }),
                                                        );
                                                },
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          );
                                        } else {
                                          return TextButton(
                                              onPressed: goToNext,
                                              child: AppWidgetsCard
                                                  .getAppointmentCard(
                                                      controller
                                                          .appointmentList[index],
                                                      goToNext, isDoctor: true));
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                ),
                              )
                              : AppWidgetsCard.getEmptyCard('Appointment');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ],
    ),
  )),
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      height: 50,
      child: LastRow(
        page: 'Appointment',
      )),
);'''
```

Comment: You should follow this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65674589/flutter-refreshing-listview-builder-with-getx

Comment: Ijaz - carry on editing the post by all means, but correct spelling is an expectation here. Use a spell-checker if necessary - all browsers have one built in.

Answer (score 0):

About the `ScrollPhysics` there are different kinds of scrolling behavior. And `AlwaysScrollableScroll` means that the ListView is able to scroll no matter whether the body size of the ListView is larger than the assigned size. By default, the ListView only scrolls when the size of the body of the ListView is larger than the assigned parent size. So to adopt the `RefreshIndicator` does not matter with the scroll physics.

To avoid the cache issues of ListView to force the ListView update, you should update the data of the ListView. You would use the `Obx` wrapper with the `ListView` and create the list like below:

```dart
List<String> data = <String>[].obs;

Obx(()=> data.value.isEmpyty ? SizedBox() : ListView(children: data.value.map((value) => Text(value)).toList())
```